# Postgres join returns doubled column when using aggregates

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a `project` table with m2m key to a `users` table and a `skills` table.

I'm trying to perform a request to postgres where in i get a list of skills and users for each project.

so in essence

```
{
  "project": "foo",
  "skills": [
    {
      "id":1,
      "name": "js"
    },
    {
      "id":2,
      "name": "py"
    }
  ],
  "members":[
    {
      "id":1,
      "name": "foo"
    },
    {
      "id":2,
      "name": "bar"
    }
  ]
}
```

i used the `json_build_object` to convert the multiple skill/users rows in to a json array

this is my sql

```
SELECT project.id AS project_id,
      project.name AS project_name,
      array_agg(json_build_object('skill_id',s.id,'name',s.skill)) AS skills,
      array_agg(json_build_object('id',p.project,'name',p.Username)) AS members

from project

    LEFT JOIN (
      select project_skills.id,project_skills.skill,project_skills.project AS name
      from project_skills
    ) s on s.name = project.name

LEFT JOIN (
  select account_projects.Username, account_projects.project AS name
  from account_projects
) p on p.name = project.name

WHERE project.id = $1
GROUP BY project_id,project_name
```

If i run this query though , the skills/users table is doubled (instead of 3 users , i get 6).

What should i be adding to the query to ensure there is no double counting?

I'm using postgres 9.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are aggregating along two different dimensions.  You should aggregate *before* joining rather than after:

```
select p.id as project_id, p.name as project_name,
       s.skills, ap.members
from project p left join
     (select s.id, s.name,
             array_agg(json_build_object('skill_id', s.id, 'name', s.skill)) as skills
      from project_skills s
      group by s.name
     ) s
     on s.name = p.name left join
     (select ap.name,
             array_agg(json_build_object('id', ap.project, 'name', ap.Username)) as members
      from account_projects ap
      group by ap.name
     ) ap
     on ap.name = p.name
where p.id = $1;
```

EDIT:

Because you are only selecting one project, it is probably cheaper to use a lateral join or correlated subquery:

```
select p.id as project_id, p.name as project_name,
       (select s.id, s.name,
               array_agg(json_build_object('skill_id', s.id, 'name', s.skill)) as skills
        from project_skills s
        where s.name = p.name
       ) skills,
       (select ap.name,
            array_agg(json_build_object('id', ap.project, 'name', ap.Username)) as members
        from account_projects ap
        where ap.name = p.name
       ) as members
from project p 
where p.id = $1;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can use jsonb instead json, query might looks like this:

```
SELECT project.id AS project_id,
      project.name AS project_name,
      jsonb_agg(DISTINCT jsonb_build_object('skill_id',s.id,'name',s.skill)) AS skills,
      jsonb_agg(DISTINCT jsonb_build_object('id',p.id,'name',p.Username)) AS members

from project

    LEFT JOIN (
      select project_skills.id,project_skills.skill,project_skills.project AS name
      from project_skills
    ) s on s.name = project.name

LEFT JOIN (
  select account_projects.id, account_projects.Username, account_projects.project AS name
  from account_projects
) p on p.name = project.name

WHERE project.id = 1
GROUP BY project_id,project_name
```

At least is to better to use jsonb_agg instead array_agg.